# Spring POST json entities

Tags: json, spring, rest, api

I'll try to make it simple, because I can't find a tutorial with this problem, I think it belongs to best practices designing REST APIs.

I have two entities
- Role (id, name)
- User (id, name, Role, etc.)

When making a POST Request to some controller what is the best approach to do it, in a json way.

```
{
"id": 1,
"name": "Luis",
"rol":{
"id": 1,
"name":Administrator,
"users" : [
//I think this is for the bidirectional relationship so 
can I avoid this property as well??
]
},
"another" : bla bla bla
}
```

For this approach do I have to put all the properties of the entity that is related?? Meaning that i have to create a json with this structure, or can ommit properties, here a question get out of my head How Spring knows this is an entity so it can make a Role object and hence a relationship to User?

Or do I have to post like this:

```
   {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Luis",
    "role_id" : 1,
    "another" : bla bla bla
    }
```

So when the controller knwos about this, first it will find a Role by using, lets say Role.findById() of course I use a service layer... and then attach it to the user.

What is the best approach for this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion this question is particularly interesting because it recalls a very common developers' pitfall i.e. understanding the borders between design and implementation.

First, let's point out a very important concept: **your API is decoupled from your business object**. Your API could be designed by an architect who knows nothing about Java or Spring and cares even less of your `User` or `Role` classes.

In REST, servers and clients exchange resources *representations* and this means that the server is free to determine the most meaningful representation for that resource. In other words, whether you are using JSON, XML or whatever, you are not forced to include in your API some information just because it's present in some form in your backing object.

Resources exposed in your API live in another dimension. They are agnostic with respect of the Spring controller.

So, the answer to your question is: **send the information that is meaningful for that operation**. The server knows the rest.

I have to admit that your second question "How Spring knows this is an entity so it can make a Role object and hence a relationship to User?" sounds a little weird to me. Spring `Controllers` bind HTTP requests to class methods. Those methods are like the following

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String createUser(@RequestBody UserModel user) {
    //...
}
```

so when you fire the POST to the right URL the request will be dispatched from the AS to your `DispatcherServlet` and finally to your `Controller` and `createUser` method. The payload, i.e. the JSON representation, is now unmarshalled into a `UserModel` class defined accordingly to your user representation (for example including `id`, `name` and `roleId`). At this point you are in control of everything since you have your `user` available for performing all the operations you need. Probably you will create a `Role` object and a `User` object, fulfill the dependencies between the two classes, calling your DAO or whathever, wait for the persistence layer to complete its operation and return your `201 created` HTTP status to the client (with the `location` header filled, if you want to be RESTful).

Comment: great explanation... about the question of how spring knows... I meant that when passing role object inside user, having this way:
`
"role":{
"id" : 1
}
`
or this way

`
"role":{
"name" : "Administrator"
}
`
or even

`
"rol":{
"id": 1,
"name":Administrator,
"users" : [
 ]
}
`
Does it fetch all the properties and then maps them to know which Role is talking about?? I mean, does it fetch ById, ByName, ByAnyOtherProperty???

Comment: You are in your controller at that point and it executes the code you wrote there. So *you* and not Spring will be fetching something using the strategy you prefer. Have in mind that at that point saveUser is executing. Probably you'll look in your UserModel instance looking for the attribute determining the role. If it's an ID, you'll perform a fetch by id. If you decide to use a different representation, you'll use another fetching strategy.